# Change constraint value in function of screen size

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 6 buttons UI like the following example:
[image]

All is perfect with non retina and retina 3.5", however, with 4" retina I have such UI:
[image]

What I think of solution is to change height constraint of every button in function of screen size programatically, I tried this code but it's not working:

```
self.todayHeightConstraint.constant =
    [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 568.0f ? 250: 250;
```

How to get rid of this white space and stretch buttons /change their constraint values in 4" screen?

Comment: In your storyboard do you have auto-layout on?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique: Yes, autolayout is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain all the buttons to be the same height, then constrain A to the top of the superview, the top of C to the bottom of A, the top of E to the bottom of C, the bottom of E to the bottom of the superview. Then constrain the center of B, D & F to the button beside them. This should cause your buttons to stick to the edges of the screen and resize equally to fill the screen regardless of screen size.

Comment: The buttons will be even resized, automatically?

Comment: How to make "the top of C to the bottom of A"? Adding just a zero vertical space between them ?

Comment: Yes. Also check that the compression resistance and content hugging resistance are set to the same values for all buttons.

Comment: They will be resized automatically. That is what autolayout does. Instead of telling the app where to put your controls, you tell it how to lay them out so it can calculate positions for everything regardless of the size of the superview. I suggest you check out the articles at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html The examples use OSX but is essentially the exact same.